# If android auto is playing and I launch the app for the first time it gets stuck on the startup screen

Tags: android-auto, just-audio, audio-service

if I launch the app and then android auto everything works correctly, even if then I close and reopen the app, it is launched. If, on the other hand, I open the app on android auto first and then open the app on the smartphone, it freezes on the startup screen.

Has anyone had the same problem?

This is my class:

```
class MediaLibrary {
  static const albumsRootId = 'stations';

  final items = <String, List<MediaItem>>{
    AudioService.browsableRootId: allMediaItems,
    albumsRootId: allMediaItems,
  };
}

class AudioPlayerHandler extends BaseAudioHandler with QueueHandler {
  final BehaviorSubject<List<MediaItem>> _recentSubject =
      BehaviorSubject.seeded(<MediaItem>[]);
  final _mediaLibrary = MediaLibrary();

  final isIOS = Platform.isIOS;

  int? get index => audioPlayer.currentIndex;

  AudioPlayerHandler() {
    _init();
  }

  Future<void> _init() async {
    final session = await AudioSession.instance;
    await session.configure(const AudioSessionConfiguration(
      avAudioSessionCategory: AVAudioSessionCategory.playback,
      avAudioSessionMode: AVAudioSessionMode.defaultMode,
      avAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy:
          AVAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy.defaultPolicy,
      avAudioSessionSetActiveOptions:
          AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptions.notifyOthersOnDeactivation,
      androidAudioAttributes: AndroidAudioAttributes(
        contentType: AndroidAudioContentType.music,
        flags: AndroidAudioFlags.none,
        usage: AndroidAudioUsage.media,
      ),
      androidAudioFocusGainType: AndroidAudioFocusGainType.gain,
      androidWillPauseWhenDucked: true,
    ));

    await getStations();

    // await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: ));

    queue.add(_mediaLibrary.items[MediaLibrary.albumsRootId]!);

    mediaItem
        .whereType<MediaItem>()
        .listen((item) => _recentSubject.add([item]));

    audioPlayer.currentIndexStream.listen((index) {
      if (index != null) mediaItem.add(queue.value[index]);
    });

    audioPlayer.playbackEventStream.listen(_broadcastState);

    audioPlayer.processingStateStream.listen((state) {
      if (state == ProcessingState.completed) stop();
    });

    // await audioHandler.addQueueItems(queue.value);

    try {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
      await audioPlayer.setAudioSource(ConcatenatingAudioSource(
        children: queue.value
            .map((item) => AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(item.id)))
            .toList(),
      ));
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<List<MediaItem>> getChildren(String parentMediaId,
      [Map<String, dynamic>? options]) async {
    switch (parentMediaId) {
      case AudioService.recentRootId:
        return _recentSubject.value;
      default:
        return _mediaLibrary.items[parentMediaId]!;
    }
  }

  @override
  ValueStream<Map<String, dynamic>> subscribeToChildren(String parentMediaId) {
    switch (parentMediaId) {
      case AudioService.recentRootId:
        final stream = _recentSubject.map((_) => <String, dynamic>{});
        return _recentSubject.hasValue
            ? stream.shareValueSeeded(<String, dynamic>{})
            : stream.shareValue();
      default:
        return Stream.value(_mediaLibrary.items[parentMediaId])
            .map((_) => <String, dynamic>{})
            .shareValue();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> skipToQueueItem(int index) async {
    if (index < 0 || index >= queue.value.length) return;
    audioPlayer.seek(Duration.zero, index: index);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> skipToPrevious() async {
    if (audioPlayer.currentIndex == 0) {
      audioPlayer.seek(Duration.zero, index: queue.value.length - 1);
    } else {
      audioPlayer.seekToPrevious();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> skipToNext() async {
    if (audioPlayer.currentIndex == queue.value.length - 1) {
      audioPlayer.seek(Duration.zero, index: 0);
    } else {
      audioPlayer.seekToNext();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> updateMediaItem(MediaItem? mediaItem) {
    this.mediaItem.add(mediaItem);
    return Future<void>.value();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> playFromMediaId(String mediaId,
      [Map<String, dynamic>? extras]) async {
    var index = queue.value.indexWhere((element) => element.id == mediaId);
    skipToQueueItem(index);
    audioHandler.play();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> play() async {
    audioPlayer.play();
    audioPlayer.icyMetadataStream.listen((_) {}).onData((data) async {
      if (data != null &&
          data.info != null &&
          mediaItem.value!.extras!['showMetadata'] == 'true') {
        print('CURRENT SONG: ${data.info!.title}');
        audioHandler.updateMediaItem(
          MediaItem(
            id: mediaItem.value!.id,
            title: data.info!.title!.split('-').last.trim(),
            artist: data.info!.title!.split('-').first.trim(),
            artUri: mediaItem.value!.artUri,
            duration: null,
            extras: {
              "longDesc": mediaItem.value!.extras!['longDesc'],
              "social": mediaItem.value!.extras!['social'],
              "socialMessage": mediaItem.value!.extras!['socialMessage'],
              "socialURL": mediaItem.value!.extras!['socialURL'],
              "website": mediaItem.value!.extras!['website'],
              "showMetadata": mediaItem.value!.extras!['showMetadata'],
              "backgroundColor": mediaItem.value!.extras!['backgroundColor'],
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    });
    readSleepTime();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> pause() async {
    audioPlayer.stop();
    if (isIOS) {
      await FlutterCarplay.popToRoot();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> stop() => audioPlayer.stop();

  void _broadcastState(PlaybackEvent event) {
    final playing = audioPlayer.playing;
    playbackState.add(
      playbackState.value.copyWith(
        controls: [
          MediaControl.skipToPrevious,
          if (playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
          MediaControl.stop,
          MediaControl.skipToNext,
        ],
        androidCompactActionIndices: const [0, 1, 3],
        processingState: const {
          ProcessingState.idle: AudioProcessingState.idle,
          ProcessingState.loading: AudioProcessingState.loading,
          ProcessingState.buffering: AudioProcessingState.buffering,
          ProcessingState.ready: AudioProcessingState.ready,
          ProcessingState.completed: AudioProcessingState.completed,
        }[audioPlayer.processingState]!,
        playing: playing,
        updatePosition: audioPlayer.position,
        bufferedPosition: audioPlayer.bufferedPosition,
        speed: audioPlayer.speed,
        queueIndex: event.currentIndex,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```